# Can someone translate "capital stacks" to Chinese?

Tags: translation, phrase

This is a financial term, and I'm hoping for the most professionally used term.

Capital Stacks:

> A description of the totality of capital invested in a project, including pure debt, hybrid debt, and equity. The stack is described as containing the most risk at the top, traveling down the stack to the position with the least risk. Higher positions in the stack expect higher returns for their capital because of the higher risk. Lenders and equity stakeholders are highly sensitive to their position in the stack. Typically, the stack is arranged as follows.

Comment: I'm proposing to remove the [tag:simplified-chinese] tag. Beyond regional variations in word choice that are correlated to use of simplified or traditional characters, it is nonsensical to speak of "translation into _simplified / traditional_ Chinese. Moreover, the tag should be used for issues specifically related to simplified characters, and I don't see why, beyond using different forms of the same character, the traditional equivalent of "capital stacks" would be different from the simplified one.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in a bilingual ppt on real estate finance. It shows capital stack means 资本结构, but as I know, English financial terms are often translated to different Chinese terms by different people, so this may be not the only one correct.

source: 中美房地产开发和金融比较/Real Estate Development and Finance in China and U.S.
http://wenku.baidu.com/view/cf8b56313968011ca30091b8.html, page 62,63.

Comment: Passer-by, thank you very much for the resource.  Very helpful and will refer to frequently for the future.